# apex does not install

Tags: oracle-apex

**hi everybody
i want to install apex 19.1 but after running code "@apexins APEX_SPACE APEX_SPACE TEMP /i/" i see this**

> SQL> @apexins APEX_SPACE APEX_SPACE TEMP /i/ ...set_appun.sql
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> ...set_ufrom_and_upgrade.sql
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> Performing installation in multitenant container database in the
>   background. The installation progress is spooled into apexins_cdb*.log
>   files.
>
> Please wait...
>
> catcon::set_log_file_base_path: ALL catcon-related output will be
>   written to [D:\apex\apexins_cdb_catcon_3764.lst]
>
> catcon::set_log_file_base_path: catcon: See [D:\apex\apexins_cdb*.log]
>   files for output generated by scripts
>
> catcon::set_log_file_base_path: catcon: See
>   [D:\apex\apexins_cdb_*.lst] files for spool files, if any
>
> catcon::validate_con_names: ORCLPDB is not open
>
> catcon::get_affected_containers: Unexpected error returned by
>   validate_con_names for default Container list
>
> catcon::catconInit2: Unexpected error returned by
>   get_affected_containers
>
> Unexpected error encountered in catconInit2; exiting
>
> Installation completed. Log files for each container can be found in:
>
> apexins_cdb*.log
>
> You can quickly scan for ORA errors or compilation errors by using a
>   utility like grep:
>
> grep ORA- *.log grep PLS- *.log

Comment: Hello, do you still need help with this? "ORCLPDB is not open" indicates that your PDB isn't open. Are you trying to install APEX in the CDB or a PDB?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new database at *Database Configuration Assistant * with a pluggable database name *pdb1*

Open cmd

Cd/apex

sqlplus / as sysdba

Select name,pdb from v$services order by name;

Alter session set container = pdb1;

Now you can run your apex commands

@apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX temp /i/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that you use a pluggable database(PDB) and Apex does not know how to deal with that if don`t configure it correctly.

The simplest workaround is to reinstall the database and during the installation uncheck the "Create as Container database":

[image]

Answer (score -1):

alter session set `container = ORCLPDB;` -- Jump this line to install on all containers

```
alter pluggable database ORCLPDB open;

@apexins APEX_SPACE APEX_SPACE TEMP /i/
```