# Installing apex 19.1

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-apex

I previously installed:

```
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
```

and want to install Apex 19.1
After entering the command @apexins.sql apex apex temp /i/
I get the following:

```
catcon::wait_for_completion: unexpected error in next_proc()

catcon::catconExec_int: unexpected error in wait_for_completion

catcon::catconExec: an error (1) was encountered

catcon.pl: unexpected error encountered in catconExec
        while running scripts against Containers at UPGRADE_LEVEL of 1; exiting
catcon::catconWrapUp: catconInit2 has not been run

catcon.pl: completed with errors
```

Had Windows 10 Home 64 bit.
I have not found a solution to this problem on the Internet, please tell me how to overcome it

I have studied similar problems: [apex does not install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035284/apex-does-not-install) and other

Comment: Check SQLNET.ORA file; doesn it contain `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)`? If not, add it and try again.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks for the reply, this line was already in the sqlnet.ora file

Comment: Is it possible you've created the database as a container database (a good thing) but you are installing APEX into the root ? (not such a good thing)

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald Thanks for the answer, I tried to create a container and a regular database, but the error was repeated